# Is it possible to output subsequent information to same line

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a script that pings an ip address and send that information to a console window. In the case of high ping times or missed pings, it is also written to a log. I would like to keep only the high ping times and missed pings in the console window and allow the good pings to overwrite each other. Is that possible?

For high ping times, this is the output (similar code is used for missed pings).

```
$out = ("{0}ms at $(get-date -format G)" -f $ping.ResponseTime)
write-host $out -foregroundcolor "yellow"
$out >> .\runningPing$ipAddress.txt
```

For normal ping times, the output is this.

```
$out ("{0}ms" -f $ping.ResponseTime)
write-host $out -foregroundcolor "green"
```

I'd like to make that last line just overwrite itself for normal pings, but let the high and missed pings push up the screen as the program runs. Is that something I can do in PS?

**SOLUTION**
Thanks to @Mathias R. Jensen, I came up with this solution:

```
  if ($ping.statuscode -eq 0) {
    if ($ping.responsetime -gt $waitTime) {
      $highPings = $highPings + 1
      $out = ("{0}ms at $(get-date -format G)" -f $ping.ResponseTime)
      [console]::SetCursorPosition(0,$highPings + $droppedPings + 1)
      write-host $out -foregroundcolor "yellow"
      $out >> $outFile
    }
    else {  
      $out = ("{0}ms $i of $pingCount" -f $ping.ResponseTime)
      [console]::SetCursorPosition(0,$highPings + $droppedPings + 2)
      write-host $out -foregroundcolor "green"
    }
  }
  else {
    $droppedPings = $droppedPings + 1
    $out = ("missed ping at $(get-date -format G)")
    [console]::SetCursorPosition(0,$highPings + $droppedPings + 1)
    write-host $out -foregroundcolor "red" 
    $out >> $outFile    
  }
```

Comment: The simple solution would be to use `Clear-Host` with an if statement or in the same block as your ping. Would that work? In console you can also do fancy foot work with backspaces

Comment: Do you want to output a line similar to old archivers' progress bar, like old `pkzip.exe` did in the line of `Compressing test.dat 2%` and overwriting that percentage with higher values over time? I doubt it, Powershell doesn't like messing with streams. I've checked with `$h=[char]8` (Ctrl+H, a backspace) and no, outputting this didn't alter the previous part of the string, so maybe it's not possible in Powershell's own window.

Comment: @Matt clear-host would clear old warning messages too, so no dice.

Comment: You could accomplish this with `[console]::SetCursorPosition($x,$y)` but I would prefer something like briantist's solution with `Write-Progress` over fiddling with the console cursor

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen This was exactly what I needed. I used the counters I had been keeping track of dropped and high pings with to push the cursor down the appropriate number of lines. I temporarily ran into a problem with the good ping writing over the top of the last high or missed ping, but otherwise it worked great. Thank you

Comment: Cool, glad to help. I'll post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the cursor position can be controlled by this method:

```
[control]::SetCursorPosition([int]$x,[int]$y)
```

The `[console]` type accelerator points to the same [`Console`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Console(v=vs.110).aspx) class that enables you to `WriteLine()` to the console in a C# console application. You can also control colors and other console behavior if you feel like it:

```
Clear-Host
[console]::ForegroundColor = "Red"
1..10|%{
    [console]::SetCursorPosition(2+$_,$_-1)
    [console]::WriteLine("Hello World!")
}
[console]::ForegroundColor = "Green"
```

[image: System.Console rules]

Answer (score 4):

I think you should use `Write-Progress` for the good pings. You don't need to give a percentage, and you can use the `-Status` parameter to show just the last good one.

Here's a small example I wrote that might demonstrate how it would look/operate (you can execute this yourself to see, it doesn't ping anything it's just a simulation):

```psh
$goods = 0
0..100 | % {
    if ((Get-Random -Minimum 0 -Maximum 100) -ge 50) {
        $goods += 1
        Write-Progress -Activity Test -Status "Last good ping: $_ ($goods total good pings)"
    } else {
        Write-Warning "Bad ping"
    }
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}
```

In this case you could have even calculated, for example a percentage of good pings and used that in `Write-Progress` but I wanted to show that you don't need to use it as a progress bar for it to be useful.

Comment: This accomplishes my original goal. It keeps everything in the same place, and it gives me something to look at to verify that the process is still running. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

[briantist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31031062/3829407) has the better approach to this but I was playing around and came up with this as well. It will not work in ISE but should do it's job on the PowerShell console. It uses `` "`b" `` which is the backspace character so that the text will overwrite itself on the console host write. Might not help you but could be useful to others.

```psh
switch($ping.ResponseTime){
    {$_ -ge 0 -and $_ -le 100}{
        $out = "{0}ms" -f $_
        $options = @{ForegroundColor = "Green"; NoNewline = $true}
        $backup = "`b" * $out.Length
    }
    {$_ -ge 500 -and $_ -le 900}{
        $out = "{0}ms at $(get-date -format G)" -f $_
        $options = @{ForegroundColor = "Yellow"; NoNewline = $false}
        $backup = "`n"
    }
}

Write-Host "$backup$out" @options
```

Uses a `switch` to set the options based on the the range of ping times. Sets a small hash table which is splatted to the `write-host`. Not perfect but it shows another way to do it.

Again this mostly done for fun.